# FusionChart not working on iOS Devices like iPhone

Tags: fusioncharts

We are having a problem where the FusionChart works fine on laptop but it does not work on iOS Devices. Wondering if anybody else is having a similar issue. It simply does not show the chart.

Comment: Will you be able to share a fiddle or something so that we can also check the issue. Also check your device and its related settings to be sure that you have JavaScript enabled in it. Many time it is the device itself that creates the problem. FusionCharts works perfectly on devices.

Answer (score 2):

FusionCharts is a JavaScript charting library, in iOS devices charts are rendered using WebView component. You have to enable JavaScript in your project and then invoke HTML & JavaScript code to UIWebView component by adding its reference to viewController.

To parse the data you can use NSXMLParser for XML data or NSJSONParser for JSON data, these class libraries are native. JSONKit and Swifyjson are also frequently used parsing libraries for Objective-C and Swift respectively.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at https://github.com/AnyChart/anychart-ios-objc-sample sample for both iPhone and iPad
http://www.anychart.com/integrations/ (i work in that company)

Comment: Your profile implies you have some connection with anychart.com. Posting a link-only "answer" to your site without disclosing your affiliation is spam. You should read [this Help Center page about promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).